# Why does PyCallGraph2 describe itself while profiling "Hello, World"?

Tags: python, pycallgraph

Suppose we have the following file labelled `hello.py`:

```py
print('Hello, World.')
```

and we run PyCallGraph on it:

```bash
$ pycallgraph graphviz hello.py
Hello, World.
```

which produces the file `pycallgraph.png` which we can inspect:

[image]

Is there a use case or justification for having `pycallgraph2` included in this output?

Comment: This looks like a bug introduced when this version was forked from the original PyCallGraph - it's excluding classes matching the pattern `'pycallgraph.*'`, but its own classes no longer match that pattern due to the `2` that was added.  You could try adding `-e "pycallgraph2.*"` to your command line to fix this.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, `-e "pycallgraph2.*"` removed the pycallgraph2 path of the diagram. This would suffice for an acceptable answer, if you would like to post it as one.