# How to exclude pycallgraph2 from PyCallGraph context wrapper?

Tags: pycallgraph

The following minimal working example

```py
from pycallgraph2 import PyCallGraph
from pycallgraph2.output import GraphvizOutput

with PyCallGraph(output=GraphvizOutput()):
    None
```

produces this output:

[image]

[Why does PyCallGraph2 describe itself while profiling "Hello, World"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74102511/why-does-pycallgraph2-describe-itself-while-profiling-hello-world) showed that we can exclude certain things in the namespace via the command line. Now I want to do this inside a script.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer while I formulating the question. The older documentation for [`pycallgraph`](https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/filtering.html) shows how to filter. If we make some necessary changes such as referring to `pycallgraph2` instead of `pycallgraph`, we have:

```py
from pycallgraph2 import PyCallGraph
from pycallgraph2 import Config
from pycallgraph2 import GlobbingFilter
from pycallgraph2.output import GraphvizOutput

config = Config()
config.trace_filter = GlobbingFilter(exclude=[
    'pycallgraph2.*'
])

with PyCallGraph(output=GraphvizOutput(), config=config):
    None
```

This gives the desired result:

[image]